# trying to read json file in java

Tags: java, json

I am Trying to read a JSON file from local disk but I am getting the exception below:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\test.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:101)
>       at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58)
>       at main.resources.ReadJsonFile.main(ReadJsonFile.java:23)

My code:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

try {
   Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("F:\\test.json"));
   JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
   String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
   System.out.println(name);

   long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
   System.out.println(age);

   // loop array
   JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("messages");
   Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(iterator.next());
   }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: Where is the file? Are you running this in Eclipse? Eclipse looks at the project directory for a file.

Comment: @CartesianTheater The project directory? So it completely ignores the drive letter?

Comment: And what is the confusion here? The exception message is already pretty obivous: there is no such file (or it can't be read). So ... provide the correct path, check the filename and check the access rights.

Comment: file is in f drive

Comment: I am running this code in eclipse

Comment: @CartesianTheater.... thank you I copied file in project directory now its running .. i dint knw about it ..thank you .